# java matches regex for variables

Tags: java

I want to match any string that has the pattern

```
{"id":"362237- 
any number of characters followed by
"http//:www.abc.com" 
any number of characters followed by
"id":"364121-
any number of characters followed by
"http://www.efg.com"
```

I want to match above pattern to the string below.

```
[{"id":"362237-13","http//:www.abc.com"},{"id":"364075-13","http://www.xyz.com"},{"id":"364121-13","http://www.efg.com"}]
```

Code:

```
String pttrn=".*{\"id\":"362237-.*\"http//:www.abc.com\".*\"id\":"364121-.*\"http://www.efg.com\".*";

String mtchr="[{\"id\":\"362237-13\",\"http//:www.abc.com\"},{\"id":\"364075-13\",\"http://www.xyz.com\"},{\"id\":\"364121-13\",\"http://www.efg.com\"}]";


        boolean b = Pattern.matches(pttrn, mtchr);
        System.out.println("b is !!" + b);
```

I was expecting b to be true but it returns false. I have got the regex wrong.

Please let me know how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: you sure you want `http:\\ ` instead of `http://`.  Also, when defining a pattern, you have to be careful of `\\ ` because it is the escape character of the string so `\\ ` inside your string `pttrn` will be escaped to just `\ `...

Comment: fixed http:\\ to http://

Comment: What do you want? To deserialize some JSON? If so, why not use some lib like Google GSON?

Comment: I want to check if the json has the ids and URLs that I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your curly brace to the regex engine with a backslash.  ...and you'll need to escape the backslash to Java with another backslash.

```
String pttrn=".*\\{\"id\":\"362237-.*\"http//:www.abc.com\".*\"id\":\"364121-.*\"http://www.efg.com\".*";
String mtchr="[{\"id\":\"362237-13\",\"http//:www.abc.com\"},{\"id\":\"364075-13\",\"http://www.xyz.com\"},{\"id\":\"364121-13\",\"http://www.efg.com\"}]";
boolean b = Pattern.matches(pttrn, mtchr);
System.out.println("b is !!" + b);
```

Comment: It's a sad day when a correct answer doesn't get followed up on and accepted.

Comment: Or viewed 128 times (and counting) and not even up-voted.